# ANSI_PADDING on varbinary(16) not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

When I add a new fixed-length varbinary column with a default constraint of `0x00000000000000000000000000000000` to an existing non-empty table, the existing records in the table are receiving a trimmed version of the default constraint, `0x00`.

Subsequent inserts of new records do correctly apply the default constraint.

This only occurs in SQL 2017, previous versions of SQL correctly apply the default constraint to all existing records.

Including 'SET ANSI_PADDING ON' does not impact the result.

`0x11111111110000000`... also behaves in same manner, where it trims the trailing zeroes.

I have also tried using a default of `DEFAULT Cast(0x00000000000000000000000000000000 as varbinary(16))`, but it has the same result.

---

Running Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU11) (KB4462262) - 14.0.3038.14 (X64)

---

To reproduce:

```
create table #test (id int);
insert into #test (id) values (1), (2), (3);
alter table #test add testvarbinary VARBINARY(16) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT 
DF_MyTable_NewColumn DEFAULT 0x00000000000000000000000000000000;
insert into #test (id) values (4); 
select * from #test;
```

Results in:

```
+----+------------------------------------+
| id |           testvarbinary            |
+----+------------------------------------+
|  1 | 0x00                               |
|  2 | 0x00                               |
|  3 | 0x00                               |
|  4 | 0x00000000000000000000000000000000 |
+----+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: @MitchWheat the TSQL used was as above for the add column, I just modified the table/column names, the insert afterwards was just INSERT INTO MyTable (Id) VALUES (1)  where MyTable has Id column and the NewColumn. 

As mentioned, the exact same TSQL on SQL 2016 (down to 2005) behaves the same, it only behaves differently in SQL 2017.

I'll try the Cast when I get back to my desk tomorrow.

Comment: @MitchWheat I just added edit 3 with code to reproduce.

Comment: Sorry yes, same result.

    create table #test (id int);
    insert into #test (id) values (1), (2), (3);
    alter table #test add testvarbinary VARBINARY(16) NOT NULL 
    CONSTRAINT DF_test DEFAULT 
    Cast(0x00000000000000000000000000000000 as varbinary(16));
    insert into #test (id) values (4);
    select * from #test;

gives: 

id testvarbinary
1 0x00
2 0x00
3 0x00
4 0x00000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: We have edit history here on SO. You might consider condensing your question down to a single cohesive question, without all of the separate **Edit** markers.

Comment: Thanks I have just tidied up the original post.

Comment: RE the answer below when you were testing in other versions what editions were you using? The online column add requires Enterprise/Developer edition.

Comment: And looks like it doesn't happen in 2017 express... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fb71976102758daad3830a973258c0d5

Comment: Have just tested in 2017 Express and confirmed the issue doesn't occur, so it appears to be a result of the online operation on Enterprise/Developer. Whilst that explains the issue (and I'm glad to know what is causing it), the behaviour isn't desirable in that it is returning a trimmed version of the default value, rather than the default itself.

Comment: This is a bug IMO and you should report it. But as @John worked out what caused it I took the liberty of adding a workaround to his answer so you can avoid the problem feature

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have reported on uservoice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a feature [introduced in SQL Server 2012](http://rusanu.com/2011/07/13/online-non-null-with-values-column-add-in-sql-server-11/) that allows NOT Null Columns to be added to a existing table (with a default constraint)
This was to allow not-null to be added to very large tables.

This is restricted to Enterprise Edition and functionally equivalent SKUs which is why you only see this on some instances in your testing.

The way it works is that the existing rows are left `NULL` until there are next touched and the value is retrieved from metadata.

The metadata itself is fine and can be inspected with

```
SELECT pc.default_value
FROM   tempdb.sys.system_internals_partitions p
       JOIN tempdb.sys.system_internals_partition_columns pc
         ON p.partition_id = pc.partition_id
WHERE  p.object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#test')
       AND default_value IS NOT NULL;
```

But when the values are read the change to `0x00` happens.

Interestingly - if you change your default to `0x00000000000000000000000000000001`
Then all rows get updated with the correct value:

```
id  testvarbinary
1   0x00000000000000000000000000000001
2   0x00000000000000000000000000000001
3   0x00000000000000000000000000000001
4   0x00000000000000000000000000000001
```

One possible workaround would be to make the default constraint non deterministic (and not possible to cache as a runtime constant)  to prevent the online column add. Though you then lose the performance benefits of the feature.

The following default constraint expression avoids the problem

```
DEFAULT 0x00000000000000000000000000000000 + CAST(LEFT(NEWID(),0) AS varbinary(1))
```

You should report this as a bug on [the uservoice site](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server).